# iOS 7 Change Carrier name/logo without Jailbreak

Tags: jailbreak, cellular-carriers, ios

I know it was possible in iOS 6 to change the carrier name (or logo) displayed in the status-bar.
Is there any way to do so in iOS 7, without jailbreaking the phone?

Comment: This works: http://ios.wonderhowto.com/how-to/change-your-iphone-carrier-name-logo-without-jailbreaking-0141148/ but you need to have a Mac with Lion...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**Carrier Editor**](http://uhelios.com/downloads/)

> CarrierEditor allows you to customise your iOS device’s carrier logo
>   <sup>Works on Mac OS X 10.6 or greater on any iOS without a jailbreak, but limited to devices that support a carrier.</sup>

> CarrierEditor generates a modified version of a carrier update onto your desktop and you simply use iTunes to install it.

[image]

Comment: You might want to mention the Mac Lion thing... ;)

Comment: @shub "Works on Mac OS X 10.6 or greater"

Comment: Just installed on my Snow Leopard. it works ;). I never installed it because of the website, I'm going to use it now!

Comment: Please note that this tool does not work with iOS 7 and above.

Comment: @Lukas This works fine on iOS 7? (haven't tested iOS 8)

Comment: @grgarside I tried it on iOS7 just sone time ago and it did not work. Which iOS version are you using?

Comment: @Lukas At the time, 7.0